# How to get (unordered) set difference or symmetric difference in C++?

Tags: c++, set, set-difference

I can't infer I can use [std::set_difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) from documentation, because it says sets should be ordered, which means they are not sets, but lists. Also all examples are about ordered lists, not sets.

How to know the truth?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::set_difference` is for use with arbitrary sorted inputs (pre-sorted `std::vector`s, `std::list`s, `std::deque`s, plain array, etc.), it just happens to work with `std::set` (which is sorted) too.

If you're working with `std::unordered_set` (or `std::set`, and you're okay with operating in place), you'd just use the `erase` method to remove all elements from one such set from another to get the difference, e.g.:

```
for (const auto& elem : set_to_remove) {
    myset.erase(elem);
}
```

You can also do it into a new set [with `std::copy_if`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22710331/364696); the recipe there is trivially adaptable to the case of symmetric difference (it's just two calls to `std::copy_if`, where each one runs on one input set, and is conditioned on the element not existing in other input set).

Comment: The code in this example results in segfaults.  This usage of `std::set::erase` only applies to iterators that are *part of* `myset`.  See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase): "Removes the elements in the range `[first; last)`, which must be a valid range in `*this`."

Comment: @sasquires: Oof, my mistake. It's not as elegant, but I replaced the bad code with a version that just iterates `set_to_remove` and use the by-value version of `erase`. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

`std::set` is sorted. Check out the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set):

> std::set is an associative container that contains **a sorted set** of
>   unique objects of type Key. Sorting is done using the key comparison
>   function Compare. Search, removal, and insertion operations have
>   logarithmic complexity. Sets are usually implemented as red-black
>   trees.

Therefore, you can use it in a same way as any other container that provides the required interface. The difference between `std::set` and e.g. `std::vector` is that `std::set` is sorting its elements on insertion and in case of `std::vector` you need to use `std::sort` function to get its elements sorted.

For example, if you need to `std::set_difference` for `std::unordered_set`, you can do it like this:

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<int> a {3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 9};
    std::unordered_set<int> b {3, 1, 4};

    std::set<int> c;
    std::set<int> d;
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::inserter(c, c.end()));
    std::copy(b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(d, d.end()));

    std::vector<int> diff;

    std::set_difference(c.begin(), c.end(), d.begin(), d.end(), 
                        std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));

    for (auto const i : diff)
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

See [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMTO8ADqgWF1tPYYmgl4%2BanQ2do5GLm6cisqYqn4MBMzEBAHGpuZKKmG0KWkEEQ7Oru6KqemZQXEKVcW2pdHlnACUiqgGxMgcAORSAMy2yIZYANTigzrq9cSYzEZT2OIADACCQyNjmJPTBrQkWPPoAPpKBMtrm5LDtKMGE1M6F1cbW/c7ezpswCSECCWgxW7w2tgI4yMzFsEDakwA7LINuMUeN6ugQCADkdXJgzq9puDluNmAjpINSOM4uNeOMAGyUgCslIAnOJ4QARKZI9aotEEDFYw7EY5486YS6E%2BjEpxkilUyncdlcwY8vnXPnozEEmbS4HjCSqjWorUgHVE/XobnGlGmtAeACeEGYADoXMAYR0SS7LLDKabbEp0q4IMhKcgfdpYW02tbkSaBZj7U6nG7MB7aH7xqnfV6A7QgwQQ%2BhKehI%2Bho7GjaDeQnBQA3RJEYjPC3Ycb4KhUOObeO2xNmiWnTtUXH3TChtMZrMR3Olqee%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%2BDkPQy6kgE8p9EIAsxyUN9olYWzCkSfh6HcwpSl0R0xOk%2BTqyU9TtOMvTjNa30gw65zXu87bzvWxzklcwnfukI2tl%2BMxQA%3D%3D)

Comment: So I need unordered set.